# Linking an element of a ListActivity to another Activity(parameter dependent)

Tags: java, android, json

I've got a list of events that I populate from a JSON file.
The format is:

```
{
   "eventId" : "1",
   "event" : "ABC",
   "dateStart" : "20151223",
   "dateEnd" : "20141201",
   "pin" : false,
   "attendees" : 233,
   "location" : "London",
   "description" : "A Test London event",
   "photo" : "event1.jpg",
   "status": "live",
   "goals": [ "sales", "strategies", "HR", "product people", "data scientists", "investors", "designers", "laywers", "Media", "Sales", "Retailers", "PR"]
}
```

In my `EventListActivity`, I populate an `ArrayList<Event>` with the multiple elements of this JSON. When clicking on an event, I want to go to a new screen that displays all the goals of that particular event.

So in the xml that describes the view for each event, I have an `onClick` activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp" android:paddingBottom="10dp" android:onClick="loadGoalScreen">
```

`loadGoalScreen` then goes on to the next screen that should display only the goals for the selected activity (currently it's displaying a static list of goals `String[] data = {"Strategists", "Human Resources", ...}`):

```
public void loadGoalScreen(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(EventListActivity.this, GoalCaptureActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
}
```

How can I let my `GoalCaptureActivity` screen know to display only the goals of the selected event? I.e how can I tell which event was clicked so I can cherry-pick the right element from the `ArrayList`, and then pass it onwards to the `GoalCaptureActivity` class where I will only display the goals for that particular activity?

Comment: Put all of the events in a ListView and add buttons to display that information on next activity perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data (objects, String, int etc) from one Activity to another through intent while calling the second activity as,

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, GoalCaptureActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("SELECTED_ACTIVITY", activityArra.get(i)); //put object, arrayList, but it should be serializable
    intent.putExtra("KEY_STRING", "activity_name"); //put string
    intent.putExtra("KEY_INTEGER", 2); //put int values
    intent.putExtra("KEY_BOOLEAN", true); //put boolean values
    intent.putExtra("KEY_CHAR", 'r'); //put char
    startActivity(intent);
```

And in the second activity you can get it back from intent object itself as,
Put this code in OnCreate() method of second activity,

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (null != intent) {
        MyActivity myActivity = intent.getSerializableExtra("SELECTED_ACTIVITY");
        String stringData= intent.getStringExtra("KEY_STRING");
        int numberData = intent.getIntExtra("KEY_INTEGER", 0);
        boolean booleanData = intent.getBooleanExtra("KEY_BOOLEAN", false);
        char charData = intent.getCharExtra("KEY_CHAR", 'a');
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you...